# ionic 2 unmet peer dependency @ionic-native/core@4.3.3

Tags: ionic2

When I am going to install camera, file, file transfer and filepath plugin it displays the error as unmet peer dependency @ionic-native/core@4.3.3.

Commands I used -

```
    npm install --save @ionic-native/camera @ionic-native/file @ionic-native/file-path @ionic-native/transfer
    ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save
    ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file --save
    ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer --save
    ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-filepath --save
```

Below is my packge.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "4.3.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/themeable-browser": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/youtube-video-player": "4.3.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "6.2.3",
    "cordova-browser": "4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.6.3",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "1.1.11",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "~4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser": "0.2.17",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player": "1.0.6",
    "ionic-angular": "3.7.1",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "~2.2.1",
    "ionic2-super-tabs": "4.1.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
},
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: try to update `"@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.14.0",` use 4.3.3 for this one

Comment: Whenever i am using npm install command it says => unmet peer dependency @ionic-native/core@4.3.3... What is meaning of this..i really stuck here since long time...

Comment: clear node_modules and do npm install..

Comment: `npm i -g npm` couldn't hurt as a try

Comment: still no success...